# Jacoco agent not shown code coverage for the shaded code.#jacoco

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Jacoco agent not shown code coverage for the shaded code, I am able to see the code coverage of the un shaded code, but if I shaded some code in my project then report get generated but EclEmma showing the code coverage as 0%.

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue: coverage is successfully computed on the shaded jar when it does not include relocations, but with relocations all coverage is 0%. Did you ever find a solution or a work-around?